# How do I to get linq results between two datetime?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to make a LINQ to get results among 2 dates but I cannot execute it and I am having an exception. I have tried to use `DbFunctions.TruncateTime` but it still does not working.

How do I to fix this?

**Trying**

```
model.dtIni = dtIni; //dtIni datetime param
model.dtFim = dtFim; //dtFim datetime param   

model.numeros = context.numerosSorteio.Where(n =>  
(
  n.dataCompra.Value.Date == model.dtIni.Value.Date && 
  n.dataCompra.Value.Date == model.dtFim.Value.Date)
))
```

**Exception**

> Exception thrown: 'System.NotSupportedException' in EntityFramework.dll
>
> Erro: The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Comment: Apparently `n.dataCompra` is a nullable `DateTime`? That code will throw more exceptions if that value is null...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your request to this:

```
model.numeros = context.numerosSorteio.Where(n =>  
(
  n.dataCompra >= model.dtIni && 
  n.dataCompra <= model.dtFim)
)).ToArray();
```